# IntelliJ and Jpa Buddy - SSH tunnel DB connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm working on a Java project (based on Spring Boot 2.6.x) using IntelliJ Community Edition and JPA Buddy. I want to use JPA Buddy for entity utility and Liquibase integration.

The production DB (MySQL 5.7) is reachable only by ssh tunnel.

Is there a way to configure a DB connection using ssh tunnel? How can I generate a changeLog from the production DB?

Thanks!
Miky

Comment: You have to open the ssh tunnel on your machine an then connect to your local host and port. How do you create the ssh tunnel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you speak about the PROD database - of course, a better option is to make backup/restore local copy and play with it. But regarding the first part of your question you can use `ssh port forwarding` e.g.:

```sh
ssh   -R 13306:0.0.0.0:3306 user@server -N
# 13306 your machine local port
# 3306 server remote port
```

and connect to remote MySQL server from your IntelliJ to `localhost:13306`